# Animate 2 Buttons with same value at the same time, multiple times

Tags: objective-c, animation, for-loop

I have 4-18 Buttons. Each 2 of them have the same value, written in my finishedButtons Array (Value 0+1 = equal, Value 2+3 = equal and so on)

I want now, that the buttons with the same value flash up (method flip3) and fade out (alpha = 0).

this is my code:

```
-(void) checkGameFinished {
if ([self.gameModel isGameOver]) {


   // int i=0;
   // int j=1;
   // for (i = 0, j = 1; j < [self.finishedButtons count]; i++, j++) {
        ButtonView *cv1 = (ButtonView *) self.finishedButtons[0];
        buttonView *cv2 = (ButtonView *) self.finishedButtons[1];


        [CATransaction begin]; {
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            self.boardView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            }];
            [UIView transitionWithView:cv1
                               duration:.6
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                               animations:^{ [cv1 flip3]; }
                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                                   animations:^{
                                   ((ButtonView *) self.finishedButtons[0]).alpha = 0;}
                                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {



                                                 }];
            }];
            [UIView transitionWithView:cv2
                              duration:.6
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                            animations:^{ [cv2 flip3]; }
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                                                 animations:^{
                                                     ((ButtonView *) self.finishedButtons[1]).alpha = 0;}
                                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {



                                                 }];
                            }];
            } [CATransaction commit];
   // }
```

When i just use it like it is now, it works fine. But only for the first 2 buttons. when i write the same function another time for value 2+3, 2+3 are not animated at the same time.

also, i don't know everytime, how much buttons are in my array (4-18).

so i thought, i make it with an for loop, but it doesn't work fine, so i commented it out. ( // )

thanks for every help!

EDIT: if i write the same code another time with an delay between, all works fine. but my problem is still there, that i don't know how much buttons there are... and why my for loop didn't work

Comment: transitions are for page-changes. I've never used them myself, and I've done animations a lot. Stick with the UIView animateWith functions, and I'd read the Animation and Views and View Controllers guides. (3 in total) Then core graphics, just to solidify skills

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I thinked about it and it was i +=2, j +=2, because there are each 2 Buttons and the values have to increase by 2 (0+1 -> 2+3 -> 4+5...), haha :D